# BadRequestException params not honored when catching and printing the exception

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, nestjs

In my service, I throw an exception like so:

```
    if (user == undefined) {
      throw new BadRequestException('foo', 'bar')
    }
```

In my e2e test, I execute the code like this:

```
    try {
      await apiClient()
        .post('/api/do/something')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send(/* some data */)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(201)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`error: ${e}`)
    }
```

In console, I see the following being printed:

```
console.log
    error: Error: expected 201 "Created", got 400 "Bad Request"
```

I'd like to make the error printer a bit more dev friendly, but so far I've been unsuccessful. Shouldn't `NestJS` be honoring the params specified in `BadRequestException`? The documentation sure seems to imply that. Any ideas?

[Edit]

The API client I use in my e2e tests looks like this:

```
  const apiClient = () => {
    return supertest(app.getHttpServer())
  }
```

Then I use it by `POST`ing or `GET`ting data:

```
    const { body } = await apiClient()
      .post('/api/products')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .send(SampleData)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(201)
```

or:

```
    const { body } = await apiClient().get('/api/products').expect(200)
```

As I'm getting to know `NestJS`, I'm probably not configuring things the way I should. I have not configured `NestJS` to handle exceptions (that I know of!). As for `BadRequestException`, I haven't implemented it, I'm just using the version from `@nestjs/common`. I tried calling it in different ways:

```
throw new BadRequestException()
throw new BadRequestException('foo')
throw new BadRequestException('foo', 'bar')
throw new BadRequestException({ reason: 'foo' }, 'bar')
```

I don't think I'm doing anything fancy. Just trying to bubble up the reason when I detect that a request doesn't have the data that the `NestJS` service expects. Thanks for the help Bergi!

Comment: Does your test expect 201 or 400 for this particular request?

Comment: You shouldn't `try`/`catch` exceptions in your test - just let them bubble, and they will be reported properly (with the full error message, error details, and stack trace).

Comment: @Bergi the test expects 201 but  I'm receiving 400. Ideally, I wanted to bubble up a better description when invoking BadRequestException, but the error was standard and the supplied info, missing. Thanks for the try/catch comment. I don't put them in tests, this was just to verify the exception being sent by the API.

Comment: The exception is *not* sent by the API. The API sends a JSON response, nothing more. The exception you are getting is from the `apiClient` you are using, which you told you'd expect a 201 status.

Comment: What api client are you using? How does it allow to access the response body in case of an exception? Also how did you configure next.js to handle exceptions? How did you implement `BadRequestException`? Please add all that info to your question by [edit]ing it.